# Shall I use HttpPost and HttpGet always?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My application is a single-page-application that uses ASP.NET MVC for providing views and a lot of actions as a kind of API for the browser-spa.

Actions are called using http-get others using http-post.

Typically I can call a action by both http-get as well as http-post.

My question: It is recommended to restrict all actions to how they should be used?

I only find discussions concering overloading actions by different parameters for http-get and http-post. But that is not my point. I think more regarding to security.

Comment: For methods that do some change on the background(like database changes), it is better to use `post`...for methods that just fetch data, then you use `get`...also your post call needs to be protected with `AntiForgeryToken` or another custom protection

Answer (score 1):

By default, all controller actions are marked as `[HttpPost]` behind the scenes, so you need only add the `[HttpGet]` attribute to override. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628610(v=vs.110).aspx for more information.